# Error in php code after php and mysql upgrades

Tags: mariadb, php-5.4

My server has been upgraded and since then one of my old application is not working

**PHP**

from PHP Version 5.04 to PHP Version 5.4.156.

**MYSQL**

MySQL database has been upgrade from MySQL version 4.1 to MariaDB Version 5.5.52(MySQL Compatiable).

Here am attaching some of the error codes and if anybody have any ideas please help to solve this issue.

**Error in login**

This is the error and corresponding lines of codes.

PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function import_request_variables() in
/user/jsf/public_html/guru/post_login.php on line 3 `import_request_variables ("p","p_");`

PHP Notice: Undefined index: hash in /user/jsf/public_html/guru/check_login.inc
on line 7 `$query.=$_REQUEST['hash']."' and login='".$_REQUEST['login']."'";`

PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant is_on_server - assumed 'is_on_server' in
/user/jsf/secret/defs.inc on line 2 `define (is_on_server,TRUE);`

**Error in Registration**

PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant is_on_server - assumed 'is_on_server' in
/user/jsf/secret/defs.inc on line 2, referer: [http://www.test.com/~jsf/akl/login.php](http://www.test.com/%7Ejsf/akl/login.php) `define (is_on_server,TRUE);`

PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_SERVER - assumed 'MYSQL_SERVER' in
/user/jsf/secret/defs.inc on line 13, referer: [http://www.test.com/~jsf/akl/login.php](http://www.test.com/%7Ejsf/akl/login.php) `define (MYSQL_SERVER,"hostname");`

PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_NAME - assumed 'MYSQL_NAME' in
/user/jsf/secret/defs.inc on line 14, referer: [http://www.test.com/~jsf/akl/login.php](http://www.test.com/%7Ejsf/akl/login.php) `define (MYSQL_NAME,"dbname");`

PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_PASSWORD - assumed 'MYSQL_PASSWORD'
in /user/jsf/secret/defs.inc on line 15, referer: [http://www.test.com/~jsf/akl/login.php](http://www.test.com/%7Ejsf/akl/login.php) `define (MYSQL_PASSWORD,"password");`

PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_DB - assumed 'MYSQL_DB' in
/user/jsf/secret/defs.inc on line 16, referer: [http://www.test.com/~jsf/akl/login.php](http://www.test.com/%7Ejsf/akl/login.php) `define (MYSQL_DB,"db name");`

PHP Notice: Undefined variable: error in /user/jsf/public_html/akl/register.php
on line 37, referer: [http://www.test.com/~jsf/akl/login.php](http://www.test.com/%7Ejsf/akl/login.php) `<?php if ($error)`

PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function import_request_variables() in
/user/jsf/public_html/akl/register.php on line 52, referer: [http://www.test.com/~jsf/akl/login.php](http://www.test.com/%7Ejsf/akl/login.php) `import_request_variables ('p','p_');`

Comment: That was a significant jump in versions.  `import_request_variables()` sounds like your code, not MySQL's.  What was the upgrade process?

Comment: To the first error, the `import_request_variables()` function no longer exists in your newer version. See [this info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php). So, that likely means that some of the other errors are likely related to the upgrade (things either deprecated, no longer present, and/or have to be implemented another way), and would simply need adjusting the specific code areas to match the need(s). With the `define` statements, the first parameter should be a string.